# Dark Mode Splashes Support

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Can we change the splashes in assets XSLaunchImageAssets when the dark mode is selected. 
Actually i want to display the different  images when app is in dark mode. So is there any way to do that?

Comment: That depends, on how exactly are you showing the splash screen? Are you using a LaunchScreen.xib or do you have a proper VC for it?

Comment: Actually i dont use both. I use the images for the launch. So can i change the images when dark theme is selected?

Comment: I do not think there is a way if that is how you are doing it...

Comment: I can display the normal splashes using this way.Put <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
  <string>Resources/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage</string> in info.plist and then put the content.json in the LaunchImage.launchimage folder

Comment: No, you can not change the launchimage  dynamically as app is not started at that moment.

Comment: @Jack Hua I don't want the launch image to change dynamically just want to put all those assets in the XSLaunchImageAssets and on the basis of dark or light theme images should be render. Can't we change the content.json ?

Comment: No, as I said the app is not started at that moment and it can't figure out whether you select the dark theme or not.

Comment: okay so that means i have to go for the storyboard approach. Thanks @Jack